# Firestore security when retrieving document by id denies permission

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When I directly retrieve a document using .doc().get() firestore security rues deny permission. What do I need to do to allow CRUD operations for authenticated users of my Ionic app?
I have the following function in my PWA Ionic app

````
``` async getUserProfile(): Promise<firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot> {
          const user: firebase.User = await this.authProvider.getUser();
          this.currentUser = user;
          console.log('found current user');
          this.userProfile = firebase.firestore().doc(`userProfile/${user.uid}`);
          console.log('returing userprofile', this.userProfile.get());
          return this.userProfile.get();
  }```
````

But the call to this.userprofile.get() fails due to security warning from Firestore Security rules

> found current user
> returing userprofile
> ZoneAwarePromise
> __zone_symbol__state: 0
> __zone_symbol__value: **FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.** at new e (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:92760:23) at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:102987:28
> .
> .
> .
> (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:10248:56)
> code: "permission-denied"
> name: "FirebaseError"
> toString: ƒ ()
> message: "Missing or insufficient permissions."
> stack: "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.\n    at new e

The Firestore Security Rules are set simply as

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /userProfile/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, update, get,delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

What should be the correct security rule to implement to allow authenticated users to CRUD their documents? Or the correct way to retrieve the document from the collection

UPDATE: It works directly from the simulator but not from the app
[image: Screenshot for Rules Simulator. It works there]

Answer (score 0):

Some inspiration. I use this very basic role based access to allow read and write where a normal user can read and admins can write:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        
      function googleProvider() {
        return request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == "google.com"; 
      }
      function getUserData() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data
      }
      allow read: if googleProvider() && getUserData().roles['user'] == true;      
      allow write: if googleProvider() && getUserData().roles['admin'] == true;
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

What `version` of security rules do you have?

There is a hint for the version 1:

> Security rules use version 1 by default. In version 1, recursive wildcards match one or more path items. They do not match an empty path, so match /cities/{city}/{document=**} matches documents in subcollections but not in the cities collection, whereas match /cities/{document=**} matches both documents in the cities collection and subcollections.

That could explain why you can't get the data you want.

The version 2 behaves different:

> In version 2 of the security rules, recursive wildcards match zero or more path items. match/cities/{city}/{document=**} matches documents in any subcollections as well as documents in the cities collection.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#version-2) you can see the whole docu for it.

The version should be on top of your rules like here:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in the cities collection as well as any document
    // in a subcollection.
    match /cities/{city}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using rules version 2. Sorry for not mentioning that  earlier. Surprisingly it works from the simulator directly. But not from the app. I updated the code with your version , but the error is still occuring